# Convert File Object to <img> Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file

In an Angular Component, I have a File like this and its an image:

```
public file : File;
```

How to show the image on HTML template, something like this:

```
<img [src]="file">
```

Comment: Is your file an image?

Comment: yes it is @artemArkhipov

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `FileReader's` instance's `readAsDataURL` method and pass it a `File`. It has an `onload` property to which you can assign a handler function. This will be called with `event` once the input file is read. The event's `target.result` property will have an encoded URI which you can then use as the image source.

This is how it translates to code

In your Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  url;

  onChange(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.url = event.target.result;
    };

    reader.onerror = (event: any) => {
      console.log("File could not be read: " + event.target.error.code);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);

  }

}
```

And in template:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)">

<img *ngIf="url" [src]="url">
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6wou3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: This is the most succint, easy to follow answer. THank you <3.